# How can I read in a RAW image in MATLAB?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I want to open and read a `.raw` image in MATLAB. My file can be [downloaded here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yrvpl6nkn7ic5q2/m-001-1.raw?dl=1).   I have tried the following three code snippets, but neither gives the expected results.

## Code Snippet #1

```
    row=576;  col=768;
    fin=fopen('m-001-1.raw','r');
    I=fread(fin,row*col,'uint8=>uint8'); 
    Z=reshape(I,row,col);
    Z=Z';
    k=imshow(Z);
```

It shows this picture:

[image: first]

## Code Snippet #2

```
    f=fopen('m-001-1.raw');
    a=fread(f);
    input_img = reshape(a,768, 576, 3);
    input_img = imrotate(input_img, -90);
    imwrite(input_img, 'm-001-1.jpg');
```

This saves a blank (just white) image in `.jpg` format.

## Code Snippet #3

```
    id = fopen('m-001-1.raw', 'r');
    x = fread(id, [576,768], 'short');
```

When I use `imshow(x)`, this picture shows:

[image: third]

How do I read this picture correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Peter's code (thanks btw!) works assuming that your image is grayscale.  For colour images, what you need to do is read in all of the bytes as a single 1D array as we can't use `fread` to read the data is in as a 3D matrix (at least not to my knowledge...).  After, we then reshape it so that it becomes a 3D matrix.  After we reshape the matrix, notice that this is the transposed result.  As such, we will have to either transpose each channel independently, or you can cleverly combine [`flipdim`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/flipdim.html) and [`imrotate`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imrotate.html) to do the 3D transpose for us.  I would rotate the image so that it's 90 degrees clockwise, but this would make the image mirror reflected across the columns.  I then use `flipdim` with the second parameter as `2` as I want to mirror reflect across the columns to get the original image back.

As such, what you would actually have to do is this:

```
row=576;  col=768;
fin=fopen('m-001-1.raw','r');
I=fread(fin, col*row*3,'uint8=>uint8'); %// Read in as a single byte stream
I = reshape(I, [col row 3]); %// Reshape so that it's a 3D matrix - Note that this is column major
Ifinal = flipdim(imrotate(I, -90),2); % // The clever transpose
imshow(Ifinal);
fclose(fin); %// Close the file
```

What I get is this image:

[image]

---

Alternatively, you can certainly use Peter's code, but you would use it so that you would reconstruct the image one colour plane at a time.  In other words, you can do this:

```
row=576;  col=768;
fin=fopen('m-001-1.raw','r');
I1=fread(fin, [col row],'uint8=>uint8'); %// Red channel
I2=fread(fin, [col row],'uint8=>uint8'); %// Green channel
I3=fread(fin, [col row],'uint8=>uint8'); %// Blue channel
I1 = I1.'; I2 = I2.'; I3 = I3.'; %// Transpose each channel separately
Ifinal = cat(3, I1, I2, I3); %// Create 3D matrix
imshow(Ifinal);
fclose(fin);
```

---

You'll get exactly the same image as above.

Comment: thank you for your help it's second time you help me.

Comment: How would one generalize this to an n x m image? That is, if the dimensions are not previously known. Is that possible?

Comment: @marcman No it isn't.  That's the point of a RAW image.  It stores the raw pixels themselves without any header information. You need to know how many rows and columns there are before hand.

Comment: @rayryeng: That makes sense. I guess a hack would be to `size(imread(img))` first? Also I would think  `permute(img, [2,1,3])` would work as well for the transpose. Or `flip(permute(img, [2,1,3,]), 2)` if that mirroring is necessary

Comment: @marcman I actually in the middle of changing my post to do the transpose that way... this is an old post. Thanks.

Comment: @marcman Yes... that would be a good "hack", but that's assuming you have one of the images already loaded in memory. Is this the case?  I'm assuming you don't know anything before hand.

Comment: @rayryeng: Well not necessarily. It would certainly add some overhead because you're also doing a standard `imread` call on the raw file. But it should get the job done I guess. My understanding is that the dimensions on `imread('image.raw')` will match up with the correct dimensions (source: [this post](http://photo.net/digital-darkroom-forum/00Z2YR))

Answer (score 6):

Your row/col sizes are reversed.  Since MATLAB arrays are column-major, and raster images are usually stored row-major, you need to read the image as a [col row] matrix, then transpose it.

```
row=576;  col=768;
fin=fopen('m-001-1.raw','r');
I=fread(fin, [col row],'uint8=>uint8'); 
Z=I';
k=imshow(Z)
```

The image replication is happening because you're short 768-576 = 192 pixels per line, so each line is progressively off that amount.  After 4 lines, you've made up the difference (4*192 = 768), so you have a 4-image replication.

Comment: Duh. I should have seen that.  Nice spot Peter.

Comment: thank you,you are right but images in database are color image and when i run this code it shows me a gray image

Comment: That's because it's only reading the first channel with the code above. I'll write an answer that does all three soon.

Comment: @SiminSoleymanpour - Do you require any more help? Consider accepting one of our answers.

Comment: thank you Peter for your help. "Stackoverflow" is very good.I thank all of you for your work on this site. I got introduced it to everyone  who i know.