# Reading RAW16 images in MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab, binaryfiles

I am trying to read a [RAW16 image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qr3udowhenvf87m/raw13.raw?dl=1) in MATLAB. After going through another [question here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25667140/how-can-i-read-in-a-raw-image-in-matlab), I figured I could read it like reading a file and then doing some simple matrix transposes. However, I am running into a weird problem. The image below is what I am getting[image: Weird overlap]. I do not understand why this overlap exists and am not entirely sure how to solve the issue. Could someone help?

Code:

```
fin = fopen('raw13.raw','r');
ima = fread(fin, [col*2 row],'uint8');
temp = zeros(col,row);
j=1;
for i=1:2:col*2-1
temp(j,:) = ima(i,:) + ima(i+1,:)*2^8; %The first element is the lower 8bits and the second element is the higher 8bits
j = j+1;
end
imshow(temp',[0 2^16-1])
```

Comment: What is expected size, i.e. col and row?

Comment: column = 1384 and rows = 1036. I took col*2 because when I was reading the MONO16 info from the buffer, it was as two bytes, i.e the stride = col*2

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is having the same problem as me.

It seems the .RAW file that I obtained was somehow corrupted. Using a lower version of the FlyCapture program resulted in a better RAW file and the code that I used worked like a charm

Answer (score 0):

I use col*3 in line 3 and line 5, then it displays the image well.
but i use 8 bit raw image form pointgray camera,and i dont know 'imshow(temp',[0 2^16-1])' would work...