# Reading voxel values from binary file into matlab

Tags: image, matlab, voxel

I have a 16bit voxel data set from which I need to extract the integer values for each voxel. The data set can be downloaded from [here](http://volvis.org), it is the 'Head Aneuyrism 16Bits' data set (You need to click on the blood vessels image to download the 16bit version). Its size is 512x512x512, but I don't know whether it is greyscale or color, nor if that matters. Looking at the image on the website I'd guess that it is color, but I am not sure whether the image should be taken literally.

A related question on SO is the following: [How can I read in a RAW image in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25667140/how-can-i-read-in-a-raw-image-in-matlab)

and the following on mathworks: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/63311-how-to-read-an-n-dimensioned-matrix-from-a-binary-file

Thanks to the information in the answers to these questions I managed to extract some information from the file with matlab as follows:

```
fileID=fopen('vertebra16.raw','r');

A=fread(fileID,512*512*512,'int16');

B=reshape(A,[512 512 512]);
```

I don't need to visualise the image, I only need to have the integer values for each voxel, but I am not sure whether I am reading the information in the correct way with my script.
The only way I found to try and check whether I have the correct voxel values is to visualise B using the following:

```
implay(B)
```

Now, with the code above, and then using implay(B) I get a black and white movie with a white disc in the center and black background and some black pixels moving in the disc (I tried to upload a frame of the movie, but it didn't work). Looking at the image on the website from which I downloaded the file, the movie frames I get seem quite different from that image, so I'd conclude that I do not have the correct voxel values.

Here are some questions related to my problem:

- Do I need to know whether the image is in grey scale or color to read the voxel values correctly?
- On the data set website there is only written that the data set is in 16bit format, so how do I know whether I am dealing with signed or unsigned integers?
- In the SO question linked to above they use 'uint8=>uint8'. I could not find this in the matlab manual, so I wonder whether 'uint8=>uint8' is an obsolete matlab notation for 'uint8' or if it does something different. I suspect that it does something different since if I use 'int16=>int16' instead of 'int16' in my code above I get a completely black movie with implay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you read the data correctly.

The problem when displaying it is the scale of the values. `implay` seems to assume the values to be in `[0,1]` and therefore clamps all values to be in that range, where are your data range is `[0,3000]`.

Simply doing

```
B = B / max(B(:))
```

will rescale your data to `[0,1]` and looking at the data again with

```
implay(B)
```

shows you something much more sensible.