# How do I read a RAW RGB image in MATLAB?

Tags: image, matlab, binaryfiles, bgr, file-import

I am trying to properly convert a RAW image so that I can view it in MATLAB. Image can be downloaded [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gdbfbluo9ai4ecp/test.raw?dl=0). I am using the version of the code provided in [How can I read in a RAW image in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25667140/how-can-i-read-in-a-raw-image-in-matlab#)
However, it is not working properly for me. Here is my slightly modified version below:

```
clear;
row=966;  col=1296;
fin=fopen('C:\Users\user\Desktop\test2.raw','r');
I=fread(fin, col*row*3,'uint8=>uint8'); %// Read in as a single byte stream
I = reshape(I, [col row 3]); %// Reshape so that it's a 3D matrix - Note that this is column major
Ifinal = flipdim(imrotate(I, -90),2); % // The clever transpose
imshow(Ifinal);
fclose(fin); %// Close the file
```

What I get:
[image: result]

What I should get:
[image: correct]

I'm not sure why it's not working for me but if I use an imaging program ([ImageJ](https://imagej.nih.gov/ij/download.html)) I can correctly convert the RAW file if I select Image type as '24-bit BGR'. The pixel format of the image is 8 Bit BAYRG.

Comment: I want to point out. The main reason I had trouble with this is because the MATLAB reshape function populates by column first. Therefore a transpose is necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There you go:

```
function q43127920
row=966; col=1296;
fin=fopen('test.raw','r');
I = fread(fin, col*row*3,'ubit24=>uint32');
I = reshape(I, col, row, []); 
B = uint8(bitand(bitshift(I,-00),uint32(255)));
G = uint8(bitand(bitshift(I,-08),uint32(255)));
R = uint8(bitand(bitshift(I,-16),uint32(255)));
I = cat(3,R,G,B);
Ifinal = flip(imrotate(I, -90),2);
imagesc(Ifinal);
fclose(fin);
```

Result:

[image]