# How can I read a RGB raw file in MATLAB?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, rgb, raw-file

I have a problem about reading a 8bit two-tap interleaved RGB raw file in MATLAB

I followed several answers in web, but I can not find exact form for my one.

Is there anyone can help this problem?

Following

[How can I read in a RAW image in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25667140/how-can-i-read-in-a-raw-image-in-matlab)

I wrote lines like below.

```
imraw = fread(fin, row*col*3, '*uint8');
imraw = reshape(imraw,[col,row,3]);
imfinal = flip(imrotate(imraw, -90),2); % // The clever transpose
fclose(fin);
imshow(imfinal,[])
```

But, I think something wrong. With above code, a result is like this
[image: Example of the result from above lines]

This image is enlarged image of a part of true image (about 1/8 of true image I guess).

T think something is messed up in line 2-3 (reshape, flip).

MY Raw file can be downloaded here

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1AWMpX3Rfm193M0xMkLJOZI0tPxjpsHsV?usp=sharing

And an example image in jpg is,

[Example in jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIh1S.jpg)

Thank you!!

---

2020. 7. 9. 

I solved this problem!
I think, "two-tap interleaved" is not important.

How I solve this problem

1. I investigated whole size of my raw file and I found it is 2048 X 2048 X 4.
2. Zeros appears every 4th positions. (like,  10, 200, 100, 0, 50, 5, 70, 0 ...)
3. I think my image structure is 2048*2048*(3 RGB +1 garbage)
4. So I get numbers from every first positions and get an image

[image]

So now, I think only thing I need to do is flip. haha
I hope this text will help some other people who have same problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thanks for posting research and your code. However, it is unclear what the problem is, please see [ask]. Why doesn't this code help you? Please [edit] the question to clarify why the linked post and this code doesn't work for you (does it error, are the results incorrect, ...?)

Comment: Can you explain how a "two-tap interleaved RGB file" is structured ?

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I will add some explanation about two-tap interleaved RGB file after investigation (I think it will take about 1 day)